# list items not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

hey guys i am using bourbon neat framework to create a responsive thumbnail gallery. Now it generated the css and somehow when i resize the thumbs seem to be out of position.
here the code i used

```
    * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4; }

.galleryContainer {
  *zoom: 1;
  max-width: 77.0625em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 1200px !important; }
  .galleryContainer:before, .galleryContainer:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table; }
  .galleryContainer:after {
    clear: both; }
  .galleryContainer .galleryList {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 2.35765%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid red; }
    .galleryContainer .galleryList:last-child {
      margin-right: 0; }
    .galleryContainer .galleryList ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0; }
    .galleryContainer .galleryList li {
      float: left;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      width: 20%;
      padding: 0px; }
      @media screen and (min-width: 1338px) {
        .galleryContainer .galleryList li {
          width: 10%; } }
    .galleryContainer .galleryList img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%; }
```

you can check out the problem here in my demo page here [**DEMO**](http://beautifulsoftwares.com/neat/)

Please tell me where i am doing it wrong.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the `float: left` that you have set is causing the issue when resizing. Using `li` elements in this instance I would adopt a `display-inline` block approach. You will need to add three declarations to the parent in order to remove the margin associated with `inline-block` elements.

You CSS

```
.galleryContainer .galleryList li {
float: left; <-- remove this
display: inline-block;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 20%; 
padding: 0px;
font-size: 0px;
}

.galleryContainer .galleryList ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 0px;  <-- add this
letter-spacing: 0px;  <-- add this
word-spacing: 0px;  <-- add this
}
```